# Simple Arduino/mosfet circuit failing

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I just tried to make a mosfet circuit, controlled by an arduino. It all worked fine, but after a few minutes the led stays on, even if i connect the gate directly to ground! To what i found online and know myself this circuit shouldn't fail... Does anyone know what caused this? I'm guessing the mosfet died... Below here is the circuit i set up, the mosfet is rated for up to 75W
[image: Schematic]

Comment: A link to the [datasheet for the IRLB8748PbF](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irlb8748pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535660665b2595) would have been useful ;)

Comment: Doesn't look like something that would fail very easily. Have you taken proper ESD precautions when handling the transistor?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Sorry my bad! Thanks for providing it!

Comment: @Klas-Kenny Yeah i touched a grounded metal surface everytime before handling it, the weird thing is, it failed while i was changing the gate pwm signal

Comment: Did the MOSFET get hot before it failed? I wouldn't expect it to unless there was some fault in the circuit.

Comment: Nope, not at all, at least not enough for me to feel it, i'd be suprised if it did with such a low load

Comment: `i touched a grounded metal surface everytime before handling it` - that's not sufficient. The circuit needs to be at earth potential (ESD mat for example) and then, if you are at earth potential then that'll be OK. If your circuit was floating (and acquired charge) then touching it will draw a surge current from it that could destroy gate-source.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for the feedback! I do have a grounding strap i could use instead, so any charge i got can get discharged. I don't have an esd mat/surface though, would just grounding the entire circuit be enough?

Comment: You need to have something that removes charge from the circuit you are working on so maybe an anti-static bag for ICs you have received and, connect that to ground. Alternatively, if the case is metal (of your device) then that should make a connection to ground via a 100k ohm resistor. You might need to brush up on avoiding static or, it may be something else that destroyed/shorted your device.

Comment: @Andyaka i used it on a breadboard, so no case involved, I do keep them in a box with this anti static black foam, i'll have to buy new ones anyway, but i'll be sure to be a lot more careful with those. Would putting an RC circuit over drain and source help this?

Comment: It's normally the gate-source that gets beaten up. I would suggest putting an 18 volt zener between g and s.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks again! I'll get one of those as well when getting new mosfets, luckily there's still some good electronic shops nearby